# What can I add to my bootstrap Google map div so that it auto reloads when the map size changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map div on my website. When the div changes, it does not reload the unloaded tiles. How can I force the map to auto reload / resize?

I am using the code below for my map.

```
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5076409,-0.1339493);

function initialize() {
var mapProp = {
center:myCenter,
zoom:12,
scrollwheel:false,
draggable:false,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap1"),mapProp);
var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap2"),mapProp);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position:myCenter,
});

marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a[data-toggle='tab']").on('shown.bs.tab',function(e) {
         initialize();   // map - function
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!